# Mac OS X Snow Leopard cannot install python 2.7 readline

Tags: macos

When I try

```
pip install readline
```

or

```
easy_install readline
```

I get the following error

```
Running readline-6.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/uX/uXgzCdzXEfSGJugKNxAMx++++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-XhqAku/readline-6.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-I7rsWF
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/uX/uXgzCdzXEfSGJugKNxAMx++++TI/-Tmp-//cc3nFYj0.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Altho for python 2.6.1 it finds readline-6.1.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg and works fine, fixing readline for ipython for 2.6.1. No joy for 2.7 however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [How do I stop setup.py from trying to include -arch ppc on MacOSX builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5930807/629118)